# java.io.FileNotFoundException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I written a listener which listen to queue continuously, as message arrive it should write that message to file.

```
@Override
public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag,
                           Envelope envelope,
                           AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                           byte[] body) throws IOException {
    String response = new String(body);

    String routingKey = envelope.getRoutingKey();
    String contentType = properties.getContentType();
    String correlationId = properties.getCorrelationId();
    System.out.println("response "+ counter+ " :: "+ response);
        try {
            ResponseWriter.responseWrite(response, correlationId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    Runnable task = new VariableLengthTask(this, envelope.getDeliveryTag(), channel, 1000);
    executorService.submit(task);

}
```

line in above method

```
ResponseWriter.responseWrite(response, correlationId);
```

will call below method:

```
File file =new File(defaultExcelPath);
        FileOutputStream fop = null;
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        synchronized(file) {
            try {
                List<String> datalist = new ArrayList<String>();
                // add details to datalist....
                // write to the file ..
                .....
                .....
                .....

                fop = new FileOutputStream(defaultExcelPath, true);
                writer = new PrintWriter(fop);
                for(String data : datalist) {
                    writer.println(data);
                }
                writer.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //e.printStackTrace();
                throw e;
            } finally {
                if(fop!= null) fop.close();
                if(writer!= null) writer.close();
            }
      }
```

but due to handler method listing more than 100 messages in some seconds, file writing method throws below exception

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Files\performanceEvaluator.csv (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)

how I can make the code which write to the file concurrently (or any other way..)

Comment: you are not synchronizing on the same file, each method call create new file  object and sets locks on that new object, that's why it's not synchronizing, try synchronizing on `responseWrite` since its a static method just make it synchronized

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is where the keyword `synchronized` comes into play. Declaring a function in this: `public synchronized void function()` manner does two things:

> 1. First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.
> 2. Second, when a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a synchronized method for the same object. This guarantees that changes to the state of the object are visible to all threads.

From the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

Comment: "less-known"?  Also, this isn't really an answer as such - merely a copy-paste of the Java Docs.

Comment: @FluffmeisterGeneral yes **"less known"** because most people don't know about it.

Comment: It's a very commonly-used keyword

Comment: He's already using it: just, wrongly, in a way you haven't identified.

Comment: @EJP: O homo, Modo ne dimittas eam! This post has been marked as answer, which means that the person who posted the question has found **my answer useful**!

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to just sync when needed on a well known lock your own class. Alternatively you can declare a static variable of type object and lock on that.

```
class MyClass{

    File file =new File(defaultExcelPath);
    FileOutputStream fop = null;
    PrintWriter writer = null;
   {
        try {//better to move this to its own fn. one fn one thing and probably dont need to sync this
            List<String> datalist = new ArrayList<String>();
            // add details to datalist....
            // write to the file ..
            .....
            .....
            .....
          }catch ...//compelte earlier try

       synchronized(MyClass.class) {
         try{

           // fop = ;
            writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(defaultExcelPath, true));
            for(String data : datalist) {
                writer.println(data);
            }
           // writer.close();//dont close here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //no point throwing error what will the calling code do?
            //jjust log it
            logger.warn(e,e);//if you dont have logging framework get it or make system.out 
        } finally {
             if(writer!= null) try{
           writer.close();
             }catch
            //complete
           // if(fop!= null) writer.close();
           //in this case dont need to open two objects, just wrap it in
           //but if u do have 2 object add seperate try-catch to close each inside the final
        }
    }
  }
   // not tested code please close braces etc
```

Comment: Isn't that a lot more work than adding `synchronized` to a method?

Comment: No, the separate try catch would still be needed eve if its on method. and really the collecting part List<String> datalist = new ArrayList<String>();
            // add details to datalist....
            // write to the file ..
            ..... should be on a different method.