# How to properly close a ZipInputStream in order to programatically close the zip file at the end of operations?

Tags: java

As part of my project auto-update functionality, my program downloads a zip file from a web server and then unzip it in place before relaunching the app (here below is the code logic). The zip file is supposed to be deleted after the files have been updated and before the main app is launched.

The download and files update is working well but the issue I am facing is that the line `Files.delete(file.toPath());` throws an error of type `java.nio.file.FileSystemException` with the description `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`. It seems like the call to `zis.close()` is not effectively releasing the handle on `update.zip`. Any indication on how I could fix this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String updateFileName = "update.zip";
    boolean updateSuccess=true;
    File file = new File(updateFileName);
    if (file.exists()) {
        String dir = file.getAbsolutePath();
        dir = dir.substring(0, dir.length() - 10);
        try {
            update(updateFileName, dir);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            updateSuccess = false;
            System.err.print("update failed !");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (updateSuccess) {
            try {
                System.err.print("Trying to delete  " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                Files.delete(Path.of(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.print("zip file could not be deleted after update !: " + e );
            }
        }
    }
    HO.main(args);
}

private static void update(String zipFile, String _destDir) throws IOException {
    int len;
    Pattern pattern;
    String fileName;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    File destDir = new File(_destDir);
    try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile))) {
        ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
        while (zipEntry != null) {
            File destFile = new File(destDir, fileName);
            File parentDirectory = destFile.getParentFile();
            if (!parentDirectory.exists()) parentDirectory.mkdirs();
            else {
                if (destFile.exists()) destFile.delete();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile, false);
            while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            fos.close();
            zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
        }
        zis.closeEntry();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you create a zip files and delete it after creation?

Comment: Have you tried using "try-with-resources" instead of manually closing the input stream?

Comment: You should look at that request : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40779633/java-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-pr

Comment: @Jens I do not create the zip file, it is downloaded from the webserver.

Comment: Why do you save the downloaded ZIP file? If you wrap the download stream in a `ZipInputStream` and decompress it, you don't need to delete any files.

Comment: `if (destFile.exists()) destFile.delete()`: you don't need this. `new FileOutputStream()` already does it. You're just doing it twice. Don't keep a dog and bark yourself.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne thank you I will correct this

Comment: Side note: Please consider to use the Zip File System Provider for the Java NIO.2 File API instead of using the low-level Zip API. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html and https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.zipfs/module-summary.html

Comment: @Smutje I tried and updated the code accordingly but this does not fix my issue

Comment: @saka1029 I prefer not to change to much of the program architecture. I imagine it should be possible to delete that zip file after reading it ...

Comment: @Puce thanks for the advice, I will try to use ZipFile, see if it fixes my issue ...

Comment: There is a compilation error `The local variable fileName may not have been initialized` at the line `File destFile = new File(destDir, fileName);` Then add `fileName = zipEntry.getName();` before that line and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

you should use 'try with resource' for stream if it implements closable.. check below
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

```
      if (file.exists()) {
            try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(updateFileName))) {
                zis.closeEntry();
            }
            Files.delete(Path.of(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            myApp.main(args);
        }
```

Comment: but I called explicitly `zis.close()` should it not do the trick ?

Comment: zis.close() you don't need .. since try with resource will handle closing stream correctly.

Comment: I updated my code example with your suggestion, I also copied almost the full code, in case it helps finding what is going on.